# Router backup solution with USB

Tags: backup, router, incremental-backup

I have a router sitting at an external location. I'm looking for a solution to backup router logs at scheduled intervals, incrementally, over USB.

Can someone recommend an intelligent external backup drive that comes with all the backup software already pre-installed on it. The problem is, there won't be any PC left onsite to run the backup software after the initial setup. The external backup drive needs to be able to initiate and complete the backup process all by itself.

Router: Digi Transport WR21

(I'm not sure why this question is getting downvoted. Is serverfault not the appropriate forum?)

Comment: You forgot to mention what sort of router this is?

Comment: USB drives cannot initiate a backup

Comment: @RyanBabchishin Would a NAS solution be more appropriate? A hardware component that sits on the LAN, is able to access router logs (router exposes FTP/SSH access) and periodically back them up?

Comment: You'll need some kind of computer to do something like that, unless the router can copy the logs on it's own.

Comment: You're getting downvoted because ['recommend me a product to do x'](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6112/sf-needs-its-own-shopping-link/6488#6488) questions are [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) ('not about: product recommendations').

Comment: @RyanBabchishin Some USB drives have a button that allegedly will initiate a backup. Though I suspect that in reality it only works if you first install some software on the computer to watch for the button being pressed and then initiate the backup.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler That is correct. Product recommendations are off-topic here. They are on-topic on some other SE sites including a few sites which specifically exist for recommendations such as: http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ and http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If the router supports syslog, that can be used to forward logs to a syslog server for long term storage. Even DD-WRT supports syslog.

Comment: Yes, this router does support alerting to a syslog server. Are there standalone hardware solutions available to act as syslog servers that I can attach to the LAN?

Comment: Probably. But product recommendations are off topic. http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic Syslog is an industry standard protocol that you should be able to install/enable on an existing device.